# How can I use variables on variable name?

Tags: c#

```
for (int f = 1; f <= 6; f++)
{
    textBox{f+11} = (loto[f].ToString());
}
```

Hi again,
I'm trying to learn c# on my own. Sorry for this noobish questions :)

To be more spesific, that's what I want :

A shortcut to write codes like that :

```
textBox12.Text = loto[1].ToString();
textBox11.Text = loto[2].ToString();
textBox10.Text = loto[3].ToString();
textBox9.Text = loto[4].ToString();
textBox8.Text = loto[5].ToString();
textBox7.Text = loto[6].ToString();
```

This code is working but i want to write it in a for loop

Comment: what is loto? Show all relevant code. What exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `List<TextBox>` and initialise it in the constructor, after the call to `InitialiseComponent()` that you will see in the constructor.

Here's how:

Firstly add to your form class a `List<TextBox>` as follows:

```
private List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();
```

Then initialise the list in your constructor something like this (change `Form1` to the name of your form's constructor):

```
public Form1()
{
    // ...

    InitializeComponent();

    // ...

    textboxes.Add(textBox1);
    textboxes.Add(textBox2);
    textboxes.Add(textBox3);
    // ...etc up to however many text boxes you have.
}
```

Then when you want to access the textboxes, you can do so like this:

```
for (int f = 1; f <= 6; ++f)
{
    textboxes[f+11].Text = loto[f].ToString(); // From your example.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, TextBox> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, TextBox>();

dictionary.Add(1, textbox1);
... // add the other textboxes


// access the dictionary via index
dictionary[f+11] = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your TextBox controls are already on your form. If not and you wanted to create your TextBox controls dynamically, you could do something like this:

```
for (int f = 1; f <= 6; f++)
{
    Dictionary<int, TextBox> dict = new Dictionary<int, TextBox>();
    dict.Add(f, new TextBox());
    dict[f].Location = new Point(0, f * 20);
    dict[f].Text = loto[f].ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(dict[f]);
}
```

Comment: I guess it's too high level for me.
My level on C# is ;

I created Hello World window and create my first application :  [link]http://yadi.sk/d/c3kN8S7o4O88K

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to store them in a list of dictionary and access them this way. So

- add controls to list/dictionary
- in your for loop, access them by index