# Dynamically call variables from a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a way in c# or VB to dynamically call variables from a loop? Instead of going one by one of every variable?

Imagine the following example,I want to set dog1Legs, dog2Legs, dog3Legs, Is there a way how to call them from a loop?

```
String dog1Legs;
String dog2Legs;
String dog3Legs;

for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
{

    dog(i)Legs = "test";
}
```

Comment: It's called an array of Action<T> if you really want to invoke. Otherwise it's just an array.

Comment: This is what [arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx) are for.

Comment: I asked same thing today : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249823/how-can-i-use-variables-on-variable-name/16250133#16250133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Typical solution is dictionary:

```
  Dictionary<String, String> dogs = new Dictionary<String, String>();

  dogs.Add("dog1Legs", null);
  dogs.Add("dog2Legs", null);
  dogs.Add("dog3Legs", null);

  for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    dogs["dogs" + i.ToString() + "Legs"] = "test";
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need no write the code as

```
String dog1Legs;
String dog2Legs;
String dog3Legs;

for (int i=1; i<4; i++)
{
    FieldInfo z = this.GetType().GetField("dog" + i + "Legs");
    object p = (object)this;     
    z.SetValue(p, "test");
}
```

Comment: While this can work - assuming those are fields, and not local variables - reflection is probably not the best way to handle what he needs here.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an array or list. E.g.

```
var dogLegs = new String[3];

for(int i=0; i<dogLegs.Length; i++)
{
    dogLegs[i] = "test";
}
```

Or making a `Dog` class might make sense, e.g.

```
void Main()
{
    var dogs = new List<Dog>();
    dogs.Add(new Dog { Name = "Max", Breed = "Mutt", Legs = 4 });
    foreach (var dog in dogs)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

class Dog
{
    public int Legs { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```